# Cajon Tapa Thickness For Kick Pedal Only, No Hand Use, No Snare?

Tags: cajon

I am curious as to tapa durability with a kick pedal. I am a guitar player and will never be using my hands. I want a stool and bass drum combination. No snare will be used as I already have a small stomp box with piezo which covers that range.

At a 1/4" thickness would it stand up to the punishment of a kick pedal? As a strength reference, I'm a 6ft, 230 pound guy.

I am building one very soon 1/2" body measuring about 14"^2 x 19", I will be making a 3/8" & 1/4" interchangeable tapa. But I am still interested in the community opinion, as cracking a tapa during live performance is a posibility.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem. There are such thing as "Cajon pedals" which are not as powerful as regular bass drum pedals.  You could also use a softer beater such as wire or leather  that will still produce a nice bass zound without weakening the face cover

Answer (score 0):

I use quarter inch and it holds up fine. Been doing 3 to 4 hour gigs and practices with it and it shows no sign of crapping out.

I cut a tennis ball and stuck that over a softer type mallet to save money on the mallet.  It works well.  If I need it to be more muffled, I use a blanket or thin towel and drape it over the face of the cajon.  It works well.